# Display Only the Properties of a Piped Command of Object that Match a Criteria

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

Maybe an example is best.  Using powershell to admin Office 365 (or Exchange) I want to do something like this:

```
Get-CasMailbox -Identity username | where { $_.Value -eq $false }
```

And only return properties where that value is false.  The idea is to not have to specify the property name but loop through each property of a single object/pipe and look at the value and the return name/value pair if the criteria is met.  I know this is simple and I'm probably just not thinking about it correctly.

To extend this further, for my own edification, how could I do something similar and return the property name that matched a specific property type such as Boolean, String, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, i got your question the right way

```
$Mailbox = Get-Mailbox -Identity username
$Members = Get-Member -Inputobject $Mailbox
Foreach($Property in $Members)
{
    if ($Property.Membertype -eq "Property")
    {
        $propname = $Property.name
        if ($Mailbox.$propname -eq $false) {$propname + ":" + $Mailbox.$propname}
    }
}
```

This should work too, if you use Get-CasMailbox instead of Get-Mailbox.

My Output (for my Mailbox) looks like this:

```
AntispamBypassEnabled:False
AuditEnabled:False
CalendarRepairDisabled:False
CalendarVersionStoreDisabled:False
DowngradeHighPriorityMessagesEnabled:False
EmailAddressPolicyEnabled:False
HasPicture:False
HasSpokenName:False
HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled:False
ImListMigrationCompleted:False
IncludeInGarbageCollection:False
IsAuxMailbox:False
IsExcludedFromServingHierarchy:False
IsInactiveMailbox:False
IsPersonToPersonTextMessagingEnabled:False
IsResource:False
IsRootPublicFolderMailbox:False
IsShared:False
IsSoftDeletedByDisable:False
IsSoftDeletedByRemove:False
LitigationHoldEnabled:False
MessageCopyForSendOnBehalfEnabled:False
MessageCopyForSentAsEnabled:False
ModerationEnabled:False
QueryBaseDNRestrictionEnabled:False
RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled:False
ResetPasswordOnNextLogon:False
RetentionHoldEnabled:False
UMEnabled:False
UseDatabaseRetentionDefaults:False
```

To get the Datatype of a property, you can use (in my example)

```
$Property.Definition
```

Greetings

Comment: Great, thanks.  This worked perfect.  I like powershell but when I come across a simple task that takes more than a one liner I scratch my head.

Comment: The more you do in powershell, the more you will learn. It is just a matter of time until you can write scripts like this by yourself. You're welcome :)